# Best Way to Write TestNG Tests where one Test depends on the output of another

Tags: testing, testng

I have a **TestA** that executes calls to multiple WebServices (provided by a @DataProvider) and verifies the status of each.

**TestB** then verifies further attributes of the output generated from successful runs of **TestA**.

To run these tests using **TestNG**, I tried two approaches:

1. To use a @Factory to generate Test Classes created from the output of TestA, but factories appear to be created before any Tests e.g. **TestA** are run
2. To store the output of TestA in an output collection, have TestA run at a higher **priority** then TestB, then have TestB use a DataProvider that retrieves its results from the output collection. This works and is similar to [this type of approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115822/passing-output-of-one-test-method-to-another-method-testng) except it uses priority instead of DependsOn, which would skip TestB if **any** runs of TestA failed.

**Questions**:

In case **1** above, is it possible to dynamically generate and run new test classes (like the Factory does) based on the output of a Test?

If not, is case **2** above, the recommended TestNG way, or is there a better way to do this?

**Update:**
I have also asked this question on [TestNG users group](http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/4cc6d556cc3b6a6c) as Cedric suggested

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not really possible as stated: TestNG needs to know all the test classes at initialization time so it can calculate the ordering properly, even if you create these classes with factories.

However, there are many ways to achieve what you want by simply not running tests that shouldn't depending on the output of the first test.

For example, testA could produce an empty collection so that testB will receive zero data to run on.

Please post some specific code if you need more help (and feel free to email testng-users to continue the discussion).

Comment: Thanks Cedric! I will create a runnable example and post to test-ng-users group when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

**Tests should be independent of each other with their own fixture so that they are easy to maintain, self contained and reason about.** If your scenario includes two web service invocations (flow test), where the first invocation's response acts as an input to the 2nd invocation, then make sure you do the first invocation in the `setUp()` method so that the fixture for the 2nd invocation is explicit.

Comment: He's testing web services, these are obviously not unit tests, and in such scenarios, dependencies are not just useful, they are sometimes the only way to write decent tests.

Comment: @CedricBeust I should say integration tests written using unit test frameworks...i will correct