# How to pass values into @test in testng

Tags: java, selenium, testng

During execution of first method of testng, url changes, I want to use that url in multiple @test going forward. however I am unable to pass that url in string to @beforetest. here is what it looks like.

```
public class basefile {

public string tempURL;


@BeforeClass 
public static void firstest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
String url = contr0l.getCurrentUrl();
}

@Test
public static void firstest(String url) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
System.out.println("Parameter value: "+url);
..
}
```

Anotherone which can be accomplished using same method is below.
it creates a folder with current time stamp of test execution. then it stores all screenshot on that folder. I can only pass "String filename" but how can I pass file.getAbsolutePath() or just String Savepath to screenshotmethod()

```
public class Maintest {

public string tempURL;


@BeforeClass 
public static void firstest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    //create folder to save screenshots. 
    String stamp =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd   hh mm ss").format(new Date());
    File file = new File("c:\\tmp\\"+stamp);
    file.mkdir();
    SavePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("Created folder"+file.getAbsolutePath());

}

@Test
public static void firstest(String url) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

dosomething();
screenshotmethod("didsomething"); //string filename

..
}

public static void screenshotmethod(String filename) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

// I need 2 values to gets passed here, filename and directory path.
    Screenshot screenshot = new 
    AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(contr0l);
    String filename =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd   hh mm ss'.png'").format(new Date());
    ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "jpg", new File("c:\\tmp\\" + string + filename));
    System.out.println("savepathis:::::::"+SavePath);

}
```

Comment: Why not use a global static value and use that.

Comment: It does not working on testng. local variable injection error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115822/passing-output-of-one-test-method-to-another-method-testng like this.